# Generic method to execute any method with 1 time retry using Delegates

Tags: c#, .net, delegates

I am trying to develop a mechanism using which I can execute any method with 1 retry attempt.

The retry will be triggered if an exception is encountered in the 1st run.

The basic Idea is, I will have a generic class for the retry logic, and I want to pass any method in it via delegates. And that method will be executed with 1 retry.

So far I have developed this.

```
public class RetryHandler
{
    Delegate _methodToRetry;

    // default constructor with delegate to function name.
    public RetryHandler(Delegate MethodToExecuteWithRetry)
    {
        _methodToRetry = MethodToExecuteWithRetry;
    }

    public void ExecuteWithRetry(bool IsRetryEnabled)
    {
        try
        {
            _methodToRetry.DynamicInvoke();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if (IsRetryEnabled)
            {
                // re execute method.
                ExecuteWithRetry(false);
            }
            else
            {
                // throw exception
                throw;
            }
        }

    }


}
```

Now I have a problem:

The methods which I want to pass have different Input parameters (both by number of parameters and object types) and different output parameters.

Is there any way by which I can achieve this? Basically I want to call the methods like this:

```
RetryHandler rh = new RetryHandler(MyMethod1(int a, int b));
int output = (int) rh.ExecuteWithRetry(true);

RetryHandler rh2 = new RetryHandler(MyMethod2(string a));
string output2 = (string) rh2.ExecuteWithRetry(true);
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: do you want to specify the parameters in the call ? Or are the hardcoded into the `RetryHandler` instance ?

Comment: I would like to specify them in the call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Try this:

   ```
      public void ExecuteWithRetry(bool IsRetryEnabled, params object[] args)
       {
           try
           {
               _methodToRetry.DynamicInvoke(args);
           }
           catch (Exception ex)
           {
               if (IsRetryEnabled)
               {
                   // re execute method.
                   ExecuteWithRetry(false, args);
   ```

   and call like this: `int output = (int) rh.ExecuteWithRetry(true, a, b);`
2. another option would be rwrite RetryHandler as generic method, but you need write code for any count of parameters:

   ```
   public static TReturn ExecuteWithRetry<TReturn, TParam>(bool IsRetryEnabled, Func<TParam, TReturn> func, TParam param)
   {
       // ...
       return func(param);
       // ...
   }
   ```
3. or write generic extension method so you can call:

   ```
   var f = new Func<int, int>((a) => a + 1);
   f.ExecuteWithRetry(x);
   ```

   extension class:

   ```
   public static class Ext
   {
       public static TReturn ExecuteWithRetry<TReturn, TParam>(this Func<TParam, TReturn> func, TParam param)
       {
           return func(param);
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Can you please tell me how do I pass the object[] while calling the method? thanks.

Comment: @BuggyCoder, call like this:
int output = (int) rh.ExecuteWithRetry(true, a, b);

Answer (score 4):

You an wrap the call:

```
public T Retry<T>(Func<T> func)
{
    try { return func(); }
    catch { return func(); }
}
```

This will let you to call anything returning a value:

```
public int Test(int a, int b) => a + b;
public string Test(string a) => a + a;

void Example()
{
    Console.WriteLine(Retry(() => Test(1, 2)));
    Console.WriteLine(Retry(() => Test("a")));
}
```

Comment: nice! short and effective